# Regex to remove multiple <br /> tags with possible spaces among them

Tags: php, regex

I have a form with a textarea, to that field is applied a javascript text editor which converts the line breaks to `<br />` tags, what I want is to write a php function to clean texts with many empty lines and to limit them to 1 (so 2 line breaks).

In example, if a user writes `something<br />  <br />   <br /><br />something else` (note that there are also some spaces) I want to have `something<br /><br />something else`

At the moment I have written this pattern `/(?:(?:<br \/>)\s*){3,}/s` but it doesn't match multiple `<br />` tags with spaces among them.

How should I write the correct regexp?

Comment: At the moment I have this pattern `/(?:(?:<br \/>)\s*){3,}/s` but it only matches `<br />` without spaces

Comment: update you question and add what you attempt and what error are you facing and what is your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strip_tags` function like this:

```
$text = '<p>Test<br>paragraph.</p><br /><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other   text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

More about the function [here](https://php.net/strip_tags)

If You want to leave the tag `<p>` just pass the tag as second parameter:

```
echo strip_tags($text,'<p>');
```

If You are looking to remove only `<br>` and `<br />` You can use:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(<br>|<br\s\/>)/", "", $text);
```

I think I finally got it ( if there are more than 3 `<br>` ) they will be replaced with only two:

```
$text = 'something<br />  <br />   <br /><br /> <br>something<br />else';
$text = preg_replace("/[(<br>|<br\s\/>)]{3,}/", "<br><br>", $text);
```

Comment: If I remove all the tags, I lost all the text formatting applied by the text editor (TinyMCE), I only want to avoid multiple blank lines.

Comment: Please read the documentation for this function it allows You to select what tags it can leave. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I know how the function works, but I should list all the tags except `<br />` which I actually don't want to remove totally, I want to avoid 3 or more in sequence with possible spaces among them.

Comment: Yet not what I'm asking for. I don't want to remove ALL the `<br>`, but only if there are more than 2 in a row and with spaces among them, then replace with 2 `<br>`

Comment: Please check my last entry in my answer.